# Pyspark: Dataframe's metadata is not saved

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry

Trying to add column level metadata to a dataframe.
But sadly, it got lost after a save.

In code repos, tried "transform" and "transform_df". Both, not storing columns metadata, even though
both after a transformation stored in a parquet file. Tried to set metadata:

- Thru the schema `(StructType([StructField("col", StringType(), True, metadata={...})])`
- Thru alias e.g. `df.select(F.col("col").alias("col_m", metadata={...}))`

Answer (score 0):

Are "columns metadata" you are describing being columns' descriptions ?

In a transform, you can do:

```py
    my_output.write_dataframe(
            my_df,
            column_descriptions={
                "col_1": "col 1 description"
            }
        )
```

You can refer to [this part of the docs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/output-column-metadata/).

Comment: Though about using it, but the thing is: they are limited to 800 chars; on the dataset preview will be displayed along side with column name and type; not propagated further if explicitly not set. Basically what we want is put a column metadata e.g. this column is a primary key and i don't want that this info appeared on the dataset preview